# Has it been officially announced that Star Wars Ep VII will be in 3D?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

While reading [this article](http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/scifi/star-wars-stars-told-lose-weight-episode-vii.html), I noticed the throw-away line at the end which states that the new Star Wars film due for release in 2015 will be in 3D.

Granted, I understand that most of the [tent-pole films](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent-pole_%28entertainment%29) these days are released simultaneously in 2D and 3D, but I am wondering if there has been any **official confirmation of Star Wars Ep VII being shot and presented in 3D.**

Comment: Well, the answer is obvious now. I've already seen it twice in 3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it has not been officially confirmed, not has any such indication been given.
I've gone through press releases, fan sites, wikipedia, official sites and such, and there is nothing other than production dates. But I suppose personally, they would certainly release it in 3D as most big budget films are these days.

Answer (score 6):

> 3D has become ubiquitous for most blockbusters, and next month’s Star Wars: The Force Awakens is no exception. Between **2D and 3D, 70MM IMAX and standard**, there are a multitude of different ways to be able to experience the movie.
>
> source: [Cinema Blend](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Star-Wars-Force-Awakens-Needs-Seen-IMAX-75177.html)

So there are three versions of the new Star Wars movie: 2D, standard 3D, and 70MM IMAX 3D

According to [slashfilm.com](http://www.slashfilm.com/the-force-awakens-70mm/), Director J.J. Abrams **only shot one sequence** in The Force Awakens **on 70mm IMAX film stock**, the rest was shot on 35mm film, and in an interview he claimed

> When I was watching the reels in 3D, there were a number of shots — and I know this sounds insane — that I hadn’t understood in the three-dimensional space quite the way I did when I saw them in 3D. I actually felt that there were things that were playing better in 3D. I had never felt that before. And if people have access to a theater that has laser projection, it is shockingly better.

The following images illustrate the differences between the normal 3D format and the IMAX 70MM.

Standard Widescreen
[image]

70MM IMAX
[image]

The website [Tech Insider](http://www.techinsider.io/star-wars-force-awakens-2d-or-3d-2015-12) recommends fans to watch the 3D version, but only if the movie theater accommodates the 70MM IMAX version

> Unless you're seeing this **on a true IMAX screen and in 70mm** (one of these theaters), go with the 2D tickets.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens#Release) informs that the film was released in N. America on December 18, 2015 in 4,134 theatres of which....

> ... 3,300 were 3D locations, **a record 392 IMAX screens (13 of which are 70mm)**, 451 premium large format screens, 146 D-Box locations, as well as releasing in the Dolby Vision format (High dynamic range, Rec. 2020 color) in Dolby Cinema. **Worldwide, it will be released across 940 IMAX theaters, a new record.** On December 18, 2015, the film began playing on every IMAX screen in North America for four straight weeks up to January 14, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Since the movie will be shot on film and almost without CGI, the movie most likely won't be shot in 3D.
But maybe it will be post-converted to 3D.

Comment: it's **Star Wars** and you say "*almost without CGI*"? What the hell is wrong with you? Every Star Wars film is based on science fiction featuring everything outer space. How can it *not* contain tons of CGI when everything is made up?

Comment: @kicker86 - there was practically no CGI in the first 3 Star Wars - effects shots - ships, battles etc were shot on moving camera's, shots were composited together.  Even blue-screening techniques at the time were analog.

Comment: you could explain this line from wikipedia - "*Special effects were created using almost all formats, including model work, CGI and practical effects.*"

Comment: Yes, there will be lots of CGI, but there will also be lots of practical effects. Don't forget that The Phantom Menace (which everyone derides) actually uses more practical and model (along with CG) shots than the entire first trilogy put together.

Comment: Also, Star Trek Into Darkness was shot on film and presented as 3D.

Comment: 3D cameras do exist... it is *possible* it was shot in 3D. But with 20/20 hindsight, I can say that yes it is/was *shown* in 3D (as well as 2D)